# How can I debug Android Studio Project using Bluestacks emulator?

Tags: android, debugging, bluestacks

I'm new to using Android Studio as I used Eclipse before. As my laptop has an AMD processor, i'm trying to emulate using Bluestacks - as I did in Eclipse. I can run the project fine but when I try to debug I get the following message on Bluestacks:

'Application blah (process com.example.blah) is waiting for the debugger to attach' - with the option to force close. I have tried a few things such as setting 'debuggable:true' and 'uses-permission' attribute in manifest, restarting Android studio/Bluestacks, to no avail. I can't seem to find any other info applicable to this particular situation.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Open bluestacks, press Run button, then choose Bluestacks emulator

Comment: Just generate the apk and then emulate it on Bluestacks.

Comment: Hi, no sorry, as mentioned above I can run the project fine in Bluestacks, it is when I try to debug the project in Bluestacks. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, if you found a solution could you please post it here as an answer

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi, realise this is late, but no I never did. I tend use a device or sometimes Genymotion now. Sorry I couldn't help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `SDK` folder under `platfrom-tools` run `adb connect localhost:5555` and go back to your android studio and run the project

Comment: Hi, it runs fine in Bluestacks, I get the 'waiting for debugger to attach' message when I try to debug. Thanks